# Select in mySqli not returning sort correctly and PHP not distinguishing differences

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table that contains over 16,000 records from a certain type of business.  I am querying that table to get every city on file but I'm only displaying the city once with the number of instances in which the business exists in that city.  "City #5" (City has five of these businesses) but I am getting repeats of certain cities as if their names are different and they are coming back out of order yet upon review they are not different.

I've checked for spaces or lack of spaces and cannot figure out why the query is thinking some businesses are not the same name when in fact they are.  Is there a way to be more specific in my comparison?

Example of output:

```
Ft Collins #1
Ft Morgan #1
Ft Collins #87
Ft Garland #1
Ft Morgan #13
```

(notice Ft Collins and Ft Morgan: this was copy and pasted)

This is the code:

```
$rscc = sQ("SELECT corsCity FROM      corsf
                        ORDER BY  corsCity    ASC");

if(!$rscc) {
    echo "Houston... we have a problem!";
}
else {
    $rows        = 0;
    $totalcities = 0;
    $totalrows   = 0;
    $lastcity    = 'xxxx';

    while($ccrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rscc)) {
        $currentcity = $ccrow['corsCity'];
        if ($lastcity != $currentcity) {
            if ($lastcity != 'xxxx') {
                $rows++;
                $totalcities++;
                echo "$lastcity #$rows <br>";
                $rows = 0;
            }
            $lastcity = $currentcity;
            $totalrows++;
        }
        else {
            $rows++;
            $totalrows++;
        }
    }

    echo "Total cities = $totalcities <br>";
    echo "Total businesses = $totalrows <br>";
}

$rscc->close();
```

Btw, "sQ" just represents "`$connection->query`".

Comment: Have you tried a GROUP BY col and/or DISTINCT in SELECT? That ought to take care of it.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id), corsCity FROM corsf GROUP BY corsCity ORDER BY corsCity ASC`  I mean I don't know why your are manually counting them when the DB can do a perfectly fine job itself.

Comment: I have three different counts going on.  I don't know how to ask the query to count the instances of each city, the count of each different city and the total count all at once.  I will try the GROUP BY to see if that fixes it.  I am trying to root out misspelled names as well as get an idea of business counts in each city..

Answer (score 0):

Most of this can be done in SQL and you only have a simple loop to do in PHP.

Use `GROUP BY` and `Count()` to have the numbers per cities. Use `WITH ROLLUP` to calculate the totals (and subtotals if you have several columns in the GROUP BY which is not your case)

```
SELECT corsCity AS City, COUNT(*) AS Nbr
FROM corsf 
GROUP BY corsCity WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY corsCity
```

Your query will return :

```
City        |   Nbr
-------------------
Chicago     |   8
Houston     |   10
Los Angeles |   2   
New York    |   5
NULL        |   25
```

If the City is `NULL`, its the total of all businesses

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help.  I used your suggestions and my results were better and my code much more efficient.  I still didn't understand the "WITH ROLLUP" but I will research it further on Google.

Comment: the WITH ROLLUP adds the last row in my example, the total  of all cities